# loading json into a python dict while keeping special values at their json representation

Tags: python, json, dictionary

TLDR:

I want to load a json string into a python dict, while keeping all values as they are, e.g, `null` as `null` and `true` as `true` (and not `None` or `True`).

Context:

The json files are loaded elsewhere by a different process into a database, all fields as `VARCHAR` (basically a string), so `null`s appear as literal `null`.

This python script I'm working on should do the same. It must work on `.json` files and eventually put them into the same tables in a `Snowflake` database.
I'm currently doing the ingestion using `pandas` `DataFrames` and the `Python Connector API`.

Example:

I have a string representation of a json, json_str:

```
{
  "null": null,
  "true": true,
  "false": false,
  "nested_json": {
    "null": null,
    "true": true,
    "false": false
  }
}
```

and I want to load it into a python dict, eventually having:

```
{
    'null': 'null',
    'true': 'true',
    'false': 'false',
    'nested_json': 
    {
        'null': 'null',
        'true': 'true',
        'false': 'false'
    }
}
```

Currently what I'm getting out of the box, using `json.loads(json_str)`, is:

```
{
    'null': None,
    'true': True,
    'false': False,
    'nested_json': 
    {
        'null': None,
        'true': True,
        'false': False
    }
}
```

I could get where I want by converting values, recursively keep doing that inside more nested jsons (right?). In that case, it would be nice to hear about:

1. an efficient and robust way to do so and pitfalls to watch out for.
2. more json values (other than true, false, null) that will need special treatment.

Would also be nice to hear if there's already a library that deals with this issue.

Comment: If it's JSON format - use JSON decoder. In python there're dozens of them, but generally everybody uses built-in [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Comment: Could you expand on the context - _why_ do you want e.g. `null` to be `'null'` not `None`? You'd likely have to take this into account when serialising, too, then how do you decide whether a given `'null'` was intended to be `"null"` or `null`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe : the jsons I work with are ingested to a database (elsewhere, and not pythonically) as they are, so `null` is inserted as `'null'`. My intent here, eventually, is to insert the data so it will appear the same. I don't mind holding either `'null'` or `null` (if that's even an option), but can't have `None`. Same goes for `True vs 'true'/true`. The loading to the database is done using pandas DataFrames.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to expand on the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Seems to me like you can just have a recursive function that converts python values like `None` and bools when serializing the data to json; at least one less step because you don't need to worry about transforming data when loading it.

Comment: @rv.kvetch What did you mean by "one less step"? When and how do you recommend to do so? Also, I'm not serializing the data to json at any point, only deserializing it from json as a first step.

Comment: Right, but I assume data has to be posted to the database as json data, right? At least that was my impression, so I was thinking you could work with a Python dict object as normal, and then convert it when storing the data in a db or wherever. Not sure if i'm thinking about it right though; if not, would appreciate more clarification.

Comment: @rv.kvetch Oh, I'll clarify: the data is not ingested as json. Each key gets its own column. Nested jsons are indeed ingested as json.